# Cannot disable footer for section in UITableView Grouped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using `UITableView` grouped and using multiple sections. I am using these codes to hide the footer for sections.

```
 self.tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0
 self.tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0

 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 0.0

}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    return UIView()

}
```

Only Footer for section 0 is not getting hidden.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Please help!

Comment: Given the code you posted, what's the point of even implementing either of these footer methods? If you really have more complicated code, update your question showing the actual code so we can help you find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys to bother, what I have done is I was also hiding sections and header which don't have any rows.

So one of the header was not getting hidden as I was returning empty `UIView()` in `viewForHeaderInSection`. Though I was returning 0 in `heightForHeaderInSection` for sections which don't have rows.

The problem is now solved as I am returning `nil` in `viewForHeaderInSection`.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I think you mean you are returning nil in viewForFooterInSection?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `grouped tableview` then there will be footer always and it never accepts `0 value`. But you can return `0.5` or `1` to fix your problem and no need to override `viewForFooterInSection`

Comment: Tried, but same output nothing is changed

Comment: It also matters if you are using a Storyboard (Interface Builder). Seems every Xcode upgrade brings some fun. I had a UITableViewController that may originally have been "un-grouped" but as I changed the functionality programmatically to support groups and headers I never changed the Storyboard setting to "grouped" type. This caused a footer to appear regardless of what I returned from the methods mentioned above. Once I changed it to "grouped" everything was in sync and the mystery footer view disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

Someone looking for a cleaner and precise solution should do the following

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? { nil }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat { .leastNonzeroMagnitude }
```